# Multicolour background in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plot like:

```
library(plotly)

d = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)

plot_ly(d) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~x, y = ~y)
```

I'd like to add a background in multiple colours to this plot. E.g. when x<50 orange background, and blue background otherwise. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add two `rectangle` [shapes](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-shapes-type) and move them to the background via [`layer = 'below'`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-shapes-layer).

[image]

```
library(plotly)

d = data.frame(x = 0:100, y = 0:100)

plot_ly(d) %>%
  add_lines(x = ~x, y = ~y) %>% 
  layout(shapes=list(list(type=rect, 
                          x0=min(d$x), 
                          x1=50, 
                          y0=min(d$y), 
                          y1=max(d$y), 
                          fillcolor='orange', 
                          layer='below'),
                     list(type=rect, 
                          x0=50, 
                          x1=max(d$x), 
                          y0=min(d$y),
                          y1=max(d$y), 
                          fillcolor='blue', 
                          layer='below')))
```

Comment: I think he wants x<50 , not y<50 :)

Comment: Oh no, the horror :(

Comment: @MLavoie: thanks for saving me from that embarrassment, fixed it